# 80's/90's Show/movie about a telekinetic Alien Cat crash-landed on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

When I was just a kid, I remember watching a movie or TV show. I have tried many times to find it but failed.

The details are very slim, but I strongly remember that the main character kept talking to a black cat, who I believe was an alien. The main character was possibly a pilot, as I remember him wearing a jacket that gave off that impression, but this might be conjecture.

I believe the alien cat may have crash landed on Earth, and the government had taken its ship. Now it was using the help of the main character to get it back.

The only other things I can recall, is that the cat might have been able to use telekinesis. I also recall something about a green light.

I watched this show/movie/episode in the mid to late 90's, but it looked sort of dated even then. Perhaps being a rerun from the 80's.

Comment: Could it be [*The Cat from Outer Space*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077305/)? The cat isn't black (rather the film seems b&w) but other details seem to fit.

Comment: My first thought was [Red Dwarf's "Cat"](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cat), but I don't think he's who you're after.  Fun character though.

Comment: What about [Nyan Cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY).

Comment: @TGar: Mid to late 90s TV show? No.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is Disney's [*The Cat From Outer Space*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077305) (1978).  I haven't thought about that film in years, but I loved it as a kid.

The cat is a crashed alien, which gets telekinetic and communicative abilities from its collar.

[image: movie still] [image: cat on a spaceship with various light inidcators]

Comment: You beat me to it by 41 seconds.  *The Cat From Outer Space* was one of my favorite movies as a little kid, being a fan of both outer space and cats. The collars allowed anyone holding them to engage in telekenesis and telepathy; with the collar off, The Cat turned into an ordinary cat. The ending even made me cry; it was a Disney live action movie during the period where Disney made cheesy, but well written, live action movies with great characters and good actors.

Comment: A poster might not be as handy as, say, a frame from the film itself. Just sayin'

Comment: @Gallifreyan Here you go. http://prettycleverfilms.com/files/2013/06/black-cat-moments-cat-from-outer-space-e1370189816244.jpg

Comment: @MrLister  -  I don't care for it -_- the OP does.

Comment: Wow! Yes, this is most definitely it! Strange how your mind changes things. I was positive the cat was black.

Comment: Honestly, I thought I remembered the cat as being black as well.

Comment: Salem from _Sabrina the Teenage Witch_ may have slewed your memory.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Gallifreyan.

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought about this in years. Actually totally forgot about it until seeing this answer.

Comment: I also loved this movie as a kid, so much so that I kept on making outer space collars for my cat (who looked fairly similar) hoping it'd give him telepathic/telekinetic powers.

Comment: My brother loved this movie so much his first computer password at school when he was required to use special characters was `Zunar-J-5/9`

Comment: Holy hell, blast from the past.

Comment: As a kid I wasn't able to see this movie, so I read the novelization. I remember it vividly, especially the disparity between the value of the gold needed to repair the spacecraft and the space it would need to fit into, and the cheating on the football game.

Answer (score 34):

**This sounds EXTREMELY like *The Cat from Outer Space* (1978).**, so if it is, make sure to accept Buzz's answer above.

Just in case it's not, some of the details sound like [*Assignment: Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment:_Earth) (1968), a backdoor pilot for a Gene Roddenberry TV show about an interstellar agent who intervenes in 20th century events here on Earth. Gary Seven, the interstellar agent, has a black cat named Isis, who seems to be intelligent through the episode, although it's hinted that she's actually some kind of shape shifting alien, as we get a brief glimpse of Isis as a human female.

The show wasn't accepted, and *Star Trek* went on for a third sesason, so that's all we really got about it.  ***Assignment: Earth* actually looked a LOT like *Doctor Who*,** with a brilliant alien dinking around with Earth, with a secret computer system and a "servo" that did all the things that a sonic screwdriver would have... but unlike *Doctor Who*, it had a more American Action feel to it.

[image: Gary Seven and Isis, working on the Saturn V.]

Comment: One of my least favorite parts of _Assignment: Earth_ is how the cat turns into a woman (it happens in a couple other episodes as well). I want the cat just to be a _cat_.

Answer (score 16):

There is an old Disney live-action movie called "[The Cat From Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_from_Outer_Space)" (1978). An alien cat's ship malfunctions and lands near a government research facility. A large amount of gold is needed to repair the ship. Hijinks ensue. The cat has telepathic powers, I think.

Comment: ninja'd! Well played!

Comment: I still remember the scene where they compress the gold brick to gold the size of a pencil - and somehow manage to decrease the weight as well. That Darn (Magic) Cat!

Comment: @WayneWerner It makes one wonder: if you're reducing the size and weight, what necessary properties are you preserving? The density?