# TV show with an old lady and a talking, alien cat

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the mid 90s, specifically 96 IIRC, I watched a tv show with my baby sitter.  The show aired weekly and it had an old lady and a talking cat that I believe was an alien. It spoke telepathically. It may have even had a collar, like [The Cat From Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_from_Outer_Space), but I’m not sure.

I believe the premise is the alien either crash landed or got to earth in an unplanned way and took over a cat or some such thing. The government was onto him. He ended up living with an old lady who eventually figures him out and ends up helping him shake off the government and work on geting home.

Comment: looks like this question might have been asked before: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151499/80s-90s-show-movie-about-a-telekinetic-alien-cat-crash-landed-on-earth -- cat from outer space was suggested even though year was earlier. ALF is not a cat (in fact I think he liked to eat them) but sort of similar idea.

Comment: @releseabe It looks close, but actually that movie was mentioned in the original question and I mistakenly edited it out (which is why I edited again).

Comment: They did serialize The Cat From Outer Space on the Walt Disney show on TV.  But it was only split in two parts and I don't know Walt Disney was still on in the 90s

Comment: there were more than one old star treks (STOS) that sort of could be misremembered this way: one was the Gary Seven episode (with a young, amazingly cute Terri Garr) and the other was the "witchcraft" episode where one of the aliens assumes form of black cat.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *[Sabrina The Teenage Witch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115341/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*?  The date is right, and it has a talking cat.

Comment: He wasn't an alien though.

Comment: it simply has to be this show,no other show dared to use cats as actors in the 90s.(it was a puppet of a cat that was used in the show not a real cat).

Comment: didn't speak telepathically either

Comment: He spoke in cat language. Only witches could understand him. Sabrina thought he was just a cat until she got her powers.